# How to loop through an array of coordinates to create map markers for a layerGroup?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Here's a quick snippet of what it looks like currently -- using the for loop. I only took a piece of the map to use an example:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEtCi.png)

The picture is simply showing that, as of right now, my code automatically displays all of the fire extinguishers as soon as the map loads -- which is not what I want. Please read below for a rather detailed version of my question.

```
    // Fifth Grade class teachers //

    var blower = L.marker([-38.68551, -44.12109], {icon: fiveTeacherIcon}).bindPopup('Mrs. Blower\'s class'),
        okonowski = L.marker([-55.47885, -43.41797], {icon: fiveTeacherIcon}).bindPopup('Mrs. Okonowski\'s class'),
        vermeulen = L.marker([-38.95941, -23.37891], {icon: fiveTeacherIcon}).bindPopup('Mrs. Vermeulen\'s class');

var fifthGrade = L.layerGroup([blower, okonowski, vermeulen]);

var classesOverlay = {
    "Kindergarten": kindergarten,
    "First Grade": firstGrade,
    "Second Grade": secondGrade,
    "Third Grade": thirdGrade,
    "Fourth Grade": fourthGrade,
    "Fifth Grade": fifthGrade
};

L.control.layers(classesOverlay).addTo(cmap);
```

As you can see above, this is how I display the markers for the fifth grade classes. When I click on "Fifth Grade" on the layer selection option (while viewing the map) those three markers pop-up. This is exactly what I want for my fire extinguishers.

But I want a more efficient way to do so due to the fact that I have so many coordinates. Whereas for Fifth Grade I only have three, so I didn't mind manually entering them individually.

So my question was basically asking if there's a more efficient way to do this. As I showed above, I currently have it run a for loop through the array and place them onto the map, but the problem is that I don't want the fire extinguishers to be showing the whole time; I want them to be just like I have Fifth Grade (and obviously the other grades too), where I simply select them from the layerGroups and then they all appear.

I just don't want to have to individually make a marker for every set of coordinates for the fire extinguishers, because I feel like that is really counter-productive.

I can't figure out how to make it so when selected it will run the for loop and display all of them; it only ended up displaying one set of coordinates when I attempted.

I hope this made more sense. I really appreciate you taking the time out of your day to help me!

Comment: How about pushing, whilst iterating over the `extinguishers` array, each marker instance into a separate `markers` array and then applying it to `L.layerGroup` - at least it is what your provided example code does suggest.

Comment: How would you go about writing the code for that? I'm so severely stumped haha >_<

Comment: just refactor your code base by indentifying separate tasks and providing/implementing thoroughly named functionality to/for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createMarker (coords) {

    return (new L.marker(coords, {icon: fireEx}).bindPopup('<strong>Hi! I\'m a fire extinguisher! And you are?</strong>').addTo(cmap));
}

function createMarkerGroup (markerLocationList) {
    var
        markerList = [];

    markerLocationList.forEach(function (location) {

        markerList.push(createMarker(location));
    });

    return L.layerGroup.apply(L.layerGroup, markerList);
}


var extinguishers = [
    [71.52491, -17.75391],
    [71.69129, 0.35156],
    [60.84491, -56.25],
    [49.49667, -14.41406],
    [10.66061, -33.75],
    [11.3508, -10.01953],
    [-21.45307, -22.5],
    [-50.1769, -60.46875],
    [-49.49667, -27.94922],
    [-59.88894, 36.03516],
    [-48.80686, 47.10938],
    [-49.15297, 84.72656],
    [-49.15297, 84.72656],
    [-48.80686, 47.10938]
];
var fireExtinguishers = createMarkerGroup(extinguishers);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that simply produces the same outcome as my code above. I'm looking to allow someone to select "Fire Extinguishers" under an "Emergency" layergroup, such as picking "Music Class" (refer to above) will place the marker down.

I could simply add each one individually but that sounds really counter-productive and I'm looking for an efficient way to do so.

Comment: Then I haven't fully understood the first part of your double question. If this is the case, please tell me, and I will remove my answer.

Comment: I am really sorry, Peter! I did a horrible job at explaining what I am talking about. Please refer to my question again as I have re-written the question. I hope it's easier to understand now! Thanks for helping ^_^